# Get data from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-xml, wcf-data-services

Sorry, If It is a stupid question but I am new to WCF. I have a C# project in which, I am loading a XML document (contains name of students and Id) using Linq to xml and I have to get the associated data (their due date, amount and stuff ) from a WCF service (a link is given).

How do I get the associated data from WCF service ? Do I just right click and add service reference.

Comment: "Do I just right click and add service reference. "  Try it, what's the worst that could happen?

Comment: yeah, I did that, it added a service reference in Service References folder. Do you know how to get data now ?

Comment: Instantiate the proxy (a class) that was generated and call one of the functions.  Intellisense should give you a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `WCF` methods with concrete types. You can not declare a method that returns anonymous objects, or interfaces.

Just create a `DTO` object representing you `XML`, and using `Linq to Xml` populate these `DTO`s. Then in your service methods, set the return types to these `DTO`s.

After adding the service reference, create a client proxy; like,

```
ServiceReference1.ClientProxy proxy = new ServiceReference1.ClientProxy();
var data = proxy.SomeMethod(someArguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, right click on the project, add service reference, configure A(address)B(binding)C(contract) in your project config file or through code, then create a proxy and call the webmethod.

example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/abc-of-an-endpoint-in-wcf/)